# Onpress method does not work in React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am getting an error that I do not understand when using the useState and useSetState functions that I sent as prop to the component I created.

Here is the main component which the CalcButton placed:

```
export const Calculator = () => {
  const [operationText, setOperationText] = React.useState('');
  const [operationHistory, setOperationHistory] = React.useState([]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
           <CalcButton operationText={operationText}  setOperationText={setOperationText}  />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Calcbutton.tsx Component

```
export default function CalcButton(
  operationText,
  setOperationText,

) {
  const handleClick = () => {
    setOperationText('2')
};

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleClick} style={styles.inner}>
        <View style={styles.middleInner}>
          <Text style={styles.label}>=</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
[enter image description here][1]
```

When I click CalcButton it gives that error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFfYl.png

Thanks for all helps!

Comment: Only one thing is passed in to your component, `props`.  Did you mean to use destructuring assignment (curly brackets around operationText, setOperationText)?

Comment: @James thanks for the answer I solved just the problem it was cause of

export default function CalcButton(
  operationText,
  setOperationText,

)

that line I had to use in here curly braces for props like this   {operationText,
  setOperationText} thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CalcButton component I added curly braces to my props and it works

```
export default function CalcButton(
  {operationText,
  setOperationText}

) {
  const handleClick = () => {
    setOperationText('2')
};

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleClick} style={styles.inner}>
        <View style={styles.middleInner}>
          <Text style={styles.label}>=</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: This isn't an explanation of the solution - consider adding more details to this answer.  Why was this a problem, and why did the solution work?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).